# Javascript counting the objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

just looking for a little help. I think I've overcomplicated this. Basically I'm trying to just count the objects in this array filled with different data types. I tried just to separate the objects and count them, but obviously I'm now getting both arrays and objects and counting them. The below outputs 4 when it should be 3.

Any help appreciated, still new to coding.

```
function countTheObjects(arr) {

let objects = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arr[i] === 'object')
    objects.push(arr[i]);
}
  return objects.length;
}

console.log((countTheObjects([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])))
```

Comment: You can identify whether an object is also an array with `Array.isArray`. But what will you do with sets, maps, regexes, dates, ...etc, will they count as objects or not?

Comment: Arrays are Objects which is why you’re getting the answer you are. As others have mentioned, use `Array.isArray()` to test for “array-ness”.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and Array.isArray() to do this.

Array.filter() will look at each item in the array and keep if it the return value of a callback function is true.

```js
function countTheObjects(arr) {
  return arr.filter((item) => item && typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item)).length;
}

console.log(countTheObjects([1, [], null, '', undefined, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems to return undefined?

Comment: @ah1917 than you did something different than what the answer shows.

Comment: That's strange, when I run this in the stack overflow code snippet with "Run Code Snippet" button it returns "3"

Comment: @WillD I would add `(item) => item && typeof item ...`

Comment: Yeah it runs fine for me on here, but I've tried on two separate consoles now and still receive undefined?

Comment: @WillD you missed parenthesis at the end

Comment: I don't think so. I want .length to be called on the return value of Array.filter()

Comment: @ah1917 could you post an example of how you are implementing it maybe on JS fiddle? Something else must be going wrong. For example you may have forgot to include the `return` keyword in the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
function countTheObjects(arr) {
let objects = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr[i]) && typeof arr[i] === 'object' &&  arr[i] !== null )
    objects.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(objects)
  return objects.length;
}

console.log((countTheObjects([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array based on `typeof` and also check for array and `null`.

```
const countIt = (arr) => arr.filter(item => typeof item === "object" && item !== null && Array.isArray(item) === false).length
```